# ipad - position:fixed bug on zoom in

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, ipad

I have a `div` which have a position fixed property and is working fine.

my issue is when I zoom in on my iPad, they don´t show the complete `div`; it's cut.

I have been trying a lot like the code I have below.

but I can´t figure out why on ipad its not working and on my desktop it does.

can someone give me hand with this please?

**jquery code:**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  $('#mydiv').css('left',-$(window).scrollLeft());
});
```

Comment: Try to use: `position:device-fixed;`

Answer (score 1):

May want to include the meta tag to initally set the width before doing your calcuations:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

and I would also suggest setting the scale of the page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
```

You can learn more about that here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW26